# How to add sound fro car acceleration sound in android game development

Tags: android

I am developing the app for car game. I cant able to give sound for acceleration  by looping(increasing engine sound) using Ontouchlistener for acceleration by pressing the button.

Comment: a quick thought on this ..you could have 5-6 different sounds..(as many as the gears of the car), as you press the gas the speed is increasing..you have to devide the top speed / gears..or set manually at which speed the user has to change gear and then play the particular sound

Comment: I have never done this before but you could record a short sound sample and pitch it up / play it faster as the car accelerates. You might be able to do it by OpenSL.